# Why might a full-text search not return short words even if ft_min_word_len has been lowered?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

In my MySQL configuration I've set `ft_min_word_len = 2` and rebuilt the index with a quick repair.

Is there anything else I need to do in order to be able to search for short (3 letter) words?

---

EDIT: This query

```
    SELECT *, match(`Tournament`.`Name`) against ('aaa') as score, `Tournament`.`id` FROM `tournie`.`tournaments` AS `Tournament` WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Tournament`.`id` having score > 0.1 ORDER BY `score` desc LIMIT 20
```

returns 0 records despite the existence of a record with that exact name - "aaa". I've also tried others, such as "bag" and (a classic) "bum".

Comment: Have you tried searching for 3 letter words?

Comment: Hah! Yes, thanks Robert. I get 0 record result sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you also restart mysql after making the change? You need to restart and rebuild your indexes.  Also remember that if what you are searching on appears in more than 50% of the records, mysql won't return anything. This makes testing with 10 records difficult.

Comment: Spot on. Needed a restart. *facepalm* In my defence, I expected that Workbench would do a restart automatically. Ah well...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you added `ft_min_word_len = 2`
  in

```
1 #Vi etc/my.cnf

[mysqld]

ft_min_word_len = 2

after that

#service mysqld restart
#rebuild your index
```